# Десериализация JSON с динамическим ключом

Tags: c#, json

Как мне десериализовать JSON данного вида:

```
"values": {
           "2016": 16.38,
           "2017": 16.22,
           "2018": 17.83,
           "2019": 13.94,
           "2020": 12.3,
           "2021": 23.48,
          },
```

Мне необходимо именно считать ключ, т.е. в данном случае год как integer.
Пробовал таким способом:

```
public class Values
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<int, double> _year { get; set; }
}
```

Возникло следующее исключение: **Invalid extension data attribute on 'Project.Models.Values'. Member '_year' type must implement IDictionary<string, JToken>**

Comment: Бери как строку и применяй toInt() или как оно там называется.

Comment: На JSON внимательно посмотрите и ответьте сами себе на вопрос: "Values является словарем, где ключ это дата, или Values содержит в себе словарь `_year`?". Ответ думаю очевиден...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Точно, хорошая наводка